# AZureADconnect report shows attribute name and value as null after exporting the report using PS command

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

AZureADconnect report  shows attribute name and value as null after exporting the report using PS command. Kindly let me know the cause and resolution for it.

Comment: Use this command  **Connect-AzureAD| Export-CSV 'C:\test.csv'**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command to export the result of connect-azuread.

```
Connect-AzureAD| Export-CSV 'C:\test.csv'
```

[image]

**Output--**

[image]